# CSS Grid - wrap top items to the right

Tags: css, css-grid

I am attempting to create a specific dynamic grid layout. There's two main components, a larger banner-type component (orange) and a component that is composed of several smaller components (green). On larger screens the smaller components should wrap on the side of the larger component, if not they should remain on top.

Currently I am using CSS grid to create the layout, but the larger item is essentially hardcoded to the second row. I can use media queries to change the row-start of the larger item, but the assumption is that the number of smaller items is potentially going to change. I am looking for a pure CSS solution.

```css
.body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  gap: 1.5rem;
}


.small-item {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}

.large-item {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: span 3;
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-row-end: span 2;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class='body'>
  <div class='small-item'>Small item</div>
  <div class='small-item'>Small item</div>
  <div class='small-item'>Small item</div>
  <div class='small-item'>Small item</div>
  <div class='small-item'>Small item</div>
  <div class='small-item'>Small item</div>
  <div class='small-item'>Small item</div>
  <div class='small-item'>Small item</div>
  <div class='small-item'>Small item</div>
  <div class='small-item'>Small item</div>
  <div class='small-item'>Small item</div>
  <div class='small-item'>Small item</div>
  <div class='large-item'>Large item</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The larger item should be in the second row providing there is space for additional smaller items on the right side of the larger item. If not the larger item should be pushed down.

There is no requirement to use CSS grid, flexbox would be fine.

Comment: Not sure this can be done with pure CSS except possibly with media queries.

Comment: Why are you forcing the large item to row 2? I don't understand how you want the positioning to work.

Comment: The small items are meant to wrap the large item from the right side. That's based on the designs I was provided.